# Integrals in the form $\int R(x,x^{\frac{m}{n}},x^{\frac{r}{s}},...)$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to approach integrals in the form $\int R(x,x^{\frac{m}{n}},x^{\frac{r}{s}}...)dx$

where $R(x,x^{\frac{m}{n}},x^{\frac{r}{s}})$ represents a fraction in terms of roots:

I was told to use the substitution $x=t^k$ where k is the least common multiple of the denominators of exponents of x

let's do an example:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x-\sqrt{x}}$$

$lcm(1,2) = 2$

hence $x=t^2$ and $dx=2tdt$ then:

$$\int\frac{2tdt}{t^2-t}$$
$$2\int\frac{dt}{t-1} = 2ln|(t-1)|=2ln|\sqrt{x}-1|$$

I was told in my class to use this method but I was never told WHY it works I would like to have a deeper understanding of why this method works and also see if there are more methods to approach integrals of that form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a rational function $R(u_1, \ldots, u_m)$ and rational numbers $\frac{p_1}{q_1}, \ldots, \frac{p_m}{q_m}$, and denote $q := \operatorname{lcm}(q_1, \ldots, q_m)$. Then, we can rewrite each rational number $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ as $\frac{r_i}{q}$ for some integer $r_i$. In terms of $t := x^q$, we have $x^\frac{r_i}{q} = (t^q)^{\frac{r_i}{q}} = t^{r_i}$, and $dx = q t^{q - 1} \,dt$, so that substitution gives
$$\int R\left(x^\frac{p_1}{q_1}, \ldots, x^\frac{p_m}{q_m}\right) \,dx = q \int R(t^{r_1}, \ldots, t^{r_m}) t^{q - 1} \,dt .$$
In particular, the integrand of the integral in $t$ is a product of rational functions of $t$ and hence is itself rational in $t$. But (provided you can express the roots of its denominator) you can always evaluate an indefinite integral of a rational function in a closed form in terms of elementary functions.

**Example** We can generalize the example in the question statement: For any integer $q > 1$, the substitution $x = t^q$ gives
$$\int \frac{dx}{x - x^{1 / q}} = q \int \frac{t^{q - 2} \,dt}{t^{q - 1} - 1},$$ and the substitution $u = t^{q - 1} - 1$ transforms the integral to
$$\frac{q}{q - 1} \int \frac{du}{u} = \frac{q}{q - 1} \log |u| + C = \frac{q}{q - 1} \log \left\vert x^{(q - 1) / q} - 1\right\vert + C$$

Comment: what happens if we get $\int \frac{1}{x^{\frac{m}{n}}(1+x^{\frac{m}{n}})^r}$ how would I set up the substitution

Comment: Following the procedure, there is only $1$ exponent, $\frac mn$, and so the l.c.m. is $n$. So, substitute $x = t^n$, which transforms the integral to $$n \int \frac{t^{n - m - 1} \,dt}{(1 + t^m)^r}.$$ For this particular function we can express the general solution in terms of a hypergeometric function: $$\frac{n}{n - m} {}_2 F_1\left(r, \frac nm - 1; \frac nm; -x^{\frac mn} \right) x^{1 - \frac mn} .$$

Answer (score 2):

If you do this substitution, then you always end up with a rational function, because of how you chose the power $k$. But thanks to the partial fraction decomposition we have an algorithm to integrate *any* rational function (provided that we can factorize its denominator). See [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222937/algorithm-for-integration-of-a-rational-function) for more details.

In answer to the comment: $R$ takes as arguments $x^{\frac mn}$, $x^{\frac rs}$, and some other rational powers of $x$. Since $k$ is the least common multiple of $n,s$, and so on (it may as well be any common multiple of them), then after substituting $x = t^{k}$ we get $x^{\frac mn} = t^{m\cdot \frac kn}$, $x^{\frac rs} = t^{r\cdot \frac ks}$. Since $k$ is a multiple of $n$ and $s$ we have $m\cdot \frac kn, r\cdot \frac ks \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., $t$ occurs only in natural powers. That's why after substitution you get a rational function.

Comment: "then you always end up with a rational function, because of how you chose the power k
" can you elaborate more on that part

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain that.