# Trying to learn integrals, like $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{1 + x^2} \,dx $

Tags: integration

I'm trying to learn how to calculate integrals on my own but I don't quite understand it.

I found the following exercise on the internet but I don't even know where to start. I'm really lost. Can you explain it to me at a level that is quite "for fools" like me?

> Evaluate $$
> \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^3 - 1}{1 + x^2} \,dx.
> $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm for Integration of a Rational Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222937/algorithm-for-integration-of-a-rational-function)

Comment: Plese read guidelines on how to ask questions.

Comment: @AnneBauval : "Fools like me.." the standards for a question have dropped a lot.

Comment: @AnneBauval : ok, preserving low quality of the question as you wish.

Comment: @AnneBauval : looks like we are not going to agree on what quality is, have a browse of the way questions are posed in English Mathematical journals. Also remember what Lagrange said regarding writing unnecessary bloated text.
But what "fools like me " would know after 40 years of browsing mathematical texts

Comment: @AnneBauval : fair enough, and I defer to you. Thank you for taking the time :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to evaluate this integral. Here is one rule: when you see an integral going from $0$ to $1$ and there is a "$1+x^m$" in the denominator, you may need to use the geometric series: $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x^m)^n = \frac{1}{1+x^m}. $$
So your integral becomes
$$ \int_0^1 (x^3-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\frac{1}{2n+4} - \frac{1}{2n+1}). $$ You should recognize this sum as a combination of the series for the arctangent and the series for the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 2):

Use [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) to get the integrand into the form
$$P(x)+\frac{Ax+B}{1+x^2}$$
for some polynomial $P$ and constants $A,B$. Now you can integrate $\dfrac{Ax}{1+x^2}$ with the substitution $u=x^2$; and $\dfrac{B}{1+x^2}$ is [well known](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-integral-of-int-1-x-2-1-dx).